# list of all linux commands which are not for selection

Tags: bash, shell, account-restrictions

I made a small interface for making some simple linux commands. The sort of commands one can enter are very limited and I'm certain no one would do anything intentionally malicious, however I want a list of all the commands in shell scripting that are not just for selection (`grep`, `zgrep`, etc). That way I can cancel execution if I detect one of these keywords that could alter something it's not supposed to. Is there a comprehensive list of all non-selection commands. Inputting `compgen -c` has given me a long list of commands, but I'm not sure if it's comprehensive. And it includes some selection statements too. How can I access execute commands so I can restrict them?

Comment: Or maybe restricteing execution to a group for users on `rm` and god knows what command can also work in far less complex way. no ?

Comment: One solution could also be to use a `busybox` compile with a minimum set of command and avoiding the use of other shell. You should also describe more precisly what you've done so we can really try to help you

Comment: You can't, there is no difference between what you call "selection commands" and "execute commands". What about `grep bar * > foo`? That will change the file `foo`. I can't think of a way to do this that does not involve you manually selecting the commands you want to allow. You will still have to deal with redirection and pipes etc.

Comment: @Kiwy Hi, thanks. What is a busybox compile?

Comment: @terdon It is totally okay to only allow a few commands. I am using php to `exec()` the command string. Would it be a good idea to check everything in the command string which is not in quotes (my greps are quoted, `grep 'id=2'`) and exit if it is not one of just a few commands. Or could something be inserted into a quoted string which could alter a file?

Comment: It certainly can in double quotes, for example `grep "$(cat a.txt > b.txt )" file` which would overwrite the contents of `b.txt`. You're safer with single quotes but whatever you do, if you allow output redirection (`>`) people can make changes to files. We might be able to help if you explain what exactly you want your users to be able to do and what not.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What language are you writing this in?  If its python, consider having it run commands without a shell like [subprocess.call()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) and don't set shell to true.  In addition consider doing the following, jail the execution in a specific directory so the user can't leave it (either using jail or chroot) and can only run inside.

Comment: What do you mean by “commands that are not for selection”? What are you trying to achieve with these restrictions? Usually you would enforce restrictions through file permissions. How are you going to prevent users from downloading and running their own programs?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at restricting the set of commands that can be executed, take a look at [Restricted Shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) feature. This disallows running commands that contain `/` in their name. You may copy/link commands that are allowed in a secure folder and configure `PATH`. If configured correctly, it might fit your requirement.

This restricted shell also tries to make it difficult to circumvent these restrictions. And saves you from reinventing the wheel all over again.